# Saving a model with no data in CakePHP (just create id in db)

Tags: cakephp

My CakePHP `Cart` model/table has only one field: `id`.

It hasMany `LineItems`.

I am not having success saving the Cart model alone:

```
$this->Cart->create();
$this->Cart->save();
```

Or, by passing it a `$data` array structured as follows and using `saveAssociated()`:

```
$data = array(
    'Cart' => array(),
    'LineItem' => array(
        array(
            'item_id' => $item_id,
            'qty' => $qty,
            'price_option_id' => $price_option_id
        )
    )
);
```

If I add a `useless_field` to the `Cart` table/model, and pass some data in it saves. So obviously the problem lies in my having a model with a table with just a single `id` field and not passing in any other data to save. It won't create what it must be assuming is an 'empty' record.

I have passed `'validate' => false` into the `saveAssociated` call but it doesn't make a difference (and there are no validations for this model to ignore).

Is there a way to do this? Am I missing something? Please enlighten me!

Comment: Uhm this sounds like an awkward DB design. What use has a cart table with just a primary key? Check my Cart plugin, I would say I have some experience with e-commerce and CakePHP https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-cart-plugin

Comment: This is a toy app for learning. The Cart is there just to tie the LineItems to as for now, I have no other Cart-specific data to save.

Comment: Guess you might have found an issue with the save then as it expects to have some data present because this is a pretty unusual case.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, burzum. Your plugin is great to learn from, too.

Comment: CakePHP tables require `created` and `modified` fields, or for you to define your own fields (ie you can call them whatever you want but they do the same thing).

Comment: Also, in this instance you would use `$this->Cart->set($data);$this->Cart->saveAll();`

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP tables require created and modified fields, or for you to define your own fields (ie you can call them whatever you want but they do the same thing).

In this instance you would use

```
$this->Cart->set($data);
$this->Cart->saveAll();
```

Comment: A model doesn't require created/modified fields, as far as I know (I have several without them). Using `set()` has not made a difference. The `saveAssociated()` or `saveAll()` call still returns false for a model with only an id field, even when a `hasMany` relation is being saved with it.

Comment: what version of cake are you using?